# Exclamation mark in sql string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, powerpivot

I got string in a table like this `'ABC !! DEF'` 
When I do a Select in SSMS I see them.
When I try to add them in Powerpivot, they disapear.
when I try in SQL to modify my view with a simple

`Replace(MyString, '!!',' ')` the `!!` still there. I tried also with the `char(33)` and have the same issue.

I'm using SSMS on a SQL Server 2012

It's been a while that I search all around, so I need your help!!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Is "!!" a string concatenation operator in Powerpivot?

Comment: FYI.. it is CHR(33) not Char(33).

Comment: Try to look at the bytes and see what is actually there. Just a shot in the dark but it may not really be ! characters

Comment: Are you sure it's `'!!'` (`CHAR(33) + CHAR(33)`) and not `N'‼'` (`NCHAR(8252)`)?

Comment: It shows as !! and no ! !... but it's not NCHAR(8252). I just figured the thing out... I'll explain in this post as answer... it can help people in the future! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If that is a real string, test what the actual value is. Obviously it isn't an exclamation point. You can find out like this:

```
declare @str table (string nvarchar(64))
insert into @str
values
(N'ABC !! DEF'),
(N'ABC ‼ DEF')

select 
    ASCII(SUBSTRING(string,5,1))
   ,UNICODE(SUBSTRING(string,5,1))
from @str
```

Then, you will know what you need to replace. You may have to edit the `substring` to extract the value from your actual column. Without real sample data, this is the best I could assume.

Comment: [You're going to want to treat everything as an nvarchar here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5a349/2)  The table column should be an nvarchar, and you should be using the UNICODE() function, not ASCII().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help in this issue that I have. With all the try and proposition you made, that guide me to a solution. This is the explaination...

The problem is due to an exportation of data from a tool called Evolve (a apps library/product Catalog). It generate an Excel Extract of the data. I took for granted that the extract was good but I saw a weird behaviour. Some - was exported properly. But in same case the - was a copy paste from word that gives a longer -. In the Exportation, this long - gaves me the !!, which is a error in converting the character. I figured that out by copying directly the !! symbol in SQL (gives a blank) or Outlook (gives a square with a interrogation marks in it).

This Characters is CHAR(19). I just split the original string char by char to see the value.

I fix my problem by replacing the CHAR(19) by a -. 
I ask the product owner of Evolve to correct this behaviour.

Thanks again for your comments en suggestion!